# Error after trying to give GUI different text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I am currently making a game where you need to collect coins. I want to make a gui that shows the amount of coins you have. But every time when I press save it shows this error:

> "error CS1061: 'Text' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no accessible extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'Text' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I have the code below. Please help!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GuiScript : MonoBehaviour
{
   public int score;
   public Text m_Label;

   //Update is called once per frame
   void Update()
   {
       score = GlobalVariables.score;
       m_Label.Text = score;
   }
```

}

Comment: You didn't initialize `m_Label`, you're getting a `null reference` exception.

Comment: Case is very important. `m_Label.text = score;` https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Text-text.html

Comment: I used your advise but now its giving me another error:"error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'"

Comment: @j4y_boi Correct. `int` and `string` are not the same type, you need to call `.ToString()` on `score`. `m_Label.Text = score.ToString();`

Comment: Okay! It is working now and it is up and running. Thank you!